# Basic element class swap, not showing correct alert message, using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this code I'm working on, see link:

http://jsfiddle.net/PqsAD/3/

The problem is depending on a elements class name (`.no-submit` or `.btn`) the click function should show a different alert message. Although this isnt working. Clearly I have missed something.

Would really appreciate it, if someone could help me shed some light on the matter. Thanks

Comment: errrmmmm looks like its working. I changed the button class to 'no-submit' and i got the correct different alert - [http://jsfiddle.net/PqsAD/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/PqsAD/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your handlers in that way:

```
$('.no-submit').live('click', function(){ 
    alert('The form has NOT been submitted!');
});    

$('.btn').live('click', function(){ 
    //$(this).parent().find('form').submit();
    alert('The form has been submitted!');
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PqsAD/5/

Comment: Thanks it worked...I was thinking about `.live()` but thought it should pick up the class name change without it. Goes to show you, you never know.